# PHP replacing dynamic vars

Tags: php, regex

I'm replacing a dynamic strings like this way and it works.

```
<?php
$data = 'wow@example.org|Foo|2019|....|x_Param';
$parts = explode("|", $data);

$text = 'Hello [-param_1-] Your email is [-param_0-]';
$new_text = str_replace('[-param_0-]', $parts[0], $text);
$new_text = str_replace('[-param_1-]', $parts[1], $new_text);
$new_text = str_replace('[-param_2-]', $parts[2], $new_text);
# .... param_X

echo $new_text;
# Out: Hello Foo Your email is wow@example.org

?>
```

How to improve it, the way i'm doing it is not efficient and if there 's 9999.X how to replace it..

I appreciate your help

Edi - Solution:

```
<?php
$data = 'wow@example.org|Foo|2019|....|x_Param';
$parts = explode("|", $data);

$text = 'Hello [-param_1-] Your email is [-param_0-]';

//$text = 'Hello [-param_1-] Your email is [-param_0-]';

$new_text = $text;
foreach($parts as $i => $part){
    $new_text = str_replace('[-param_'.$i.'-]', $part, $new_text);  
}

echo $new_text;


?>
```

Comment: This looks like a clear use case for [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) using `%s` placeholders instead of your custom `[-param_N]-`

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use just one str_replace, like this:

```
<?php
$data = 'wow@example.org|Foo|2019|....|x_Param';
$parts = explode("|", $data);

$text = 'Hello [-param_1-] Your email is [-param_0-]';
$params = ['[-param_0-]', '[-param_1-]', '[-param_2-]'];
$new_text = str_replace($params, $parts, $text);

echo $new_text;
# Out: Hello Foo Your email is wow@example.org

?>
```

Yes, [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) will accept arrays.

If you have loads of parameters you can generate the `$params` array using a loop, but personally I would use something more meaningful. So instead of `[-param_0-]` I would have `%%email%%`, and so on.

Comment: This is just another way,  but not efficient as well, as question said, what if we have million of param_0 ..

Comment: @Manix This is quite efficient, prove me wrong (I'll be the first to admit it), and I don't think there will be millions of parameters.

Comment: Well, calling `str_replace()` many times is less efficient than calling it once.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data = 'wow@example.org|Foo|2019|....|x_Param';
$parts = explode("|", $data);

$text = 'Hello [-param_1-] Your email is [-param_0-]';

//$text = 'Hello [-param_1-] Your email is [-param_0-]';

$new_text = $text;
foreach($parts as $i => $part){
    $new_text = str_replace('[-param_'.$i.'-]', $part, $new_text);  
}

echo $new_text;


?>
```